# How to run a command to use data from a txt file to execute them one by one smartly

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, command, mac-address

I will explain it precisely!

1. So, i have 8 friends using same internet connection which i do and mostly we play games online.
2. Connection is such that when you switch on your connection it displays a login page of ISP which allow you go online only after you login.
3. We have each others mac address.Now to check either any of my friend is online or not i execute the following command:

   `sudo ifconfig en0 ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx; sudo ifconfig en0 down; sudo ifconfig en0 ether up; sleep 6; ping -c 3 www.google.co.in;`
4. Where xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx=MAC ADDRESS, en0=ethernet
5. I use sleep as it takes about 6 seconds to connect router
6. So ping shows me result whether they are online or not
7. Now i have 8 such mac addresses in a txt file organised as each in one line.

Q1) Can i use only one command such that it takes each mac address from text file one by one and uses it in above command and ends as my txt ends?

Q2) Is there any Alternative command for above purpose as the above command is organised by myself to work properly as per my use?

I work with Mac OS

Comment: Why not set up DHCP reservations for each friend's MAC address on your router, then you can simply ping the known, reserved IP address of any friend you want to check. You leave all your computers using DHCP so they work wherever you plug them in, but on your network, each machine is always given the same IP address.

Comment: No every machine is given different ip so when i assign a manual ip it happens sometimes that it says ip already in use that is isp has given that ip to someone else SO I can ONLY RELY on MAC ADDRESSES!

Comment: i just require a single command or script which replaces xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx from above command one by one from a txt file and execute it till the lines in txt files end!

Comment: I don't see what you are trying to do, or how. Are you setting the MAC address of your network card and then seeing if it conflicts with another one in order to determine if that MAC address is in use?

Comment: yup you got it Right! but with permissions!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the final quote

```
#!/bin/bash
while read m; do
   echo Checking MAC address: $m
   sudo ifconfig en0 ether $m
   sudo ifconfig en0 down
   sudo ifconfig en0 up
   sleep 5
   i=1
  while [ $i -eq 1 ]
    do
      ping -c 3 www.google.co.in > /dev/null
      e=$?
         if [ $e -eq 0 ]
          then
            echo ONLINE
            i=0
            echo $m >> ONLINE.txt
         elif [ $e -eq 2 ]
          then
           echo OFFLINE
           i=0
           echo $m >> OFFLINE.txt
         else
           echo Waiting To be Connected
           i=1
           sleep 4
         fi
    done
done < macs.txt
echo HI, These macs are ONLINE
cat ONLINE.txt
echo Sorry these are OFFLINE
cat OFFLINE.txt
rm ONLINE.txt OFFLINE.txt
```

Thanks for helping guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **arpwatch** to keeps track for ethernet/ip address pairings.
You run it like this:

```
arpwatch -i eth0
```

And if you want to check the logs:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

Output:

> Nov 10 15:59:34 debian arpwatch: new station 192.168.1.2 0:17:9a:a:f6:44 eth0

Then you can do a bash script more easy.

A few examples like... 
Find the last log of a MAC

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | egrep -i xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

extract the time of that log

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | egrep -i xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx | awk '{print $3}'
```

or something more useful like the ip

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | egrep -i xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx | awk '{print $8}'
```

Comment: we are not connected through layer 2 connections we are just on same ISP but live at long distances. Above command which i use works to check whether the mac is online or not, but every time i need to check one by one thats hectic so i need one single command or script

Comment: Ok, so what you need to do is using `for i in $(cat macs.txt); do echo $i; done` and change the `echo $i` for the code you show us in the question but changing `sudo ifconfig en0 ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx;` for `sudo ifconfig en0 ether $i;`

Comment: it only executes operation for last mac address! BTW thnx!

Comment: You're welcome. With the echo is working to me maybe you have a problem with the pause times. This is just an approach, look at the code of Mark Setchell to see a full code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read m; do
   echo Checking MAC address: $m
   sudo ifconfig en0 ether $m
   sudo ifconfig en0 down
   sudo ifconfig en0 ether up
   sleep 6
   ping -c 3 www.google.co.in
   if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      echo Ping successful
   else
      echo Ping failed
   fi
done < MACs.txt
```

where `MACs.txt` looks like this:

```
11.22.33.44.55.66
22.33.44.55.66.77
33.44.55.66.77.88
```

**Updated Answer**

If you want it a little bit more streamlined, you might prefer this version which doesn't always wait 6 seconds - instead it pings up to 10 times with 1 second between pings and stops immediately if the ping is successful so it should be quicker.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read m; do
   echo Checking MAC address: $m
   sudo ifconfig en0 ether $m
   sudo ifconfig en0 down
   sudo ifconfig en0 ether up
   # Ping up to 10 times, stopping immediately if successful
   success=0
   for i in {1..10}; do
      ping -c 3 -t 1 www.google.co.in > /dev/null
      if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
         success=1
         break
      fi
   done
   if [ $success -eq 1 ]; then
      echo Success: $m
   else
      echo Fail: $m
   fi
done < MACs.txt
```

Comment: works awesome Thnx, but i used sleep as 6sec bcoz mostly it takes about 5-4 sec to connect ethernet after command en0 up(sometimes more than 6 sec so ping replies unknown host  and i have to manually try it again), can i make it accurate rather than precise like as my connection starts after en0 up command ping starts automatically non time specific!!! hope you understand as i wrote it little messy after all I'm not a programmer hmm!!

Comment: I have tried to improve it so it doesn't wait always 6 seconds every time and stops immediately if pinging is successful.

Comment: thnx it worked, last request, for example i have 8 macs out of which 4 give me ping successful(referring ur 1st script not updated one) and 4 give me ping failed, then at the very last(after checking all macs) it gives me an echo saying ping successful followed by the 4 macs which succeeded and ping failed followed by 4 macs which failed as my conclusion , i think we will have to introduce two new variables from which 1 will display successful ones and the other would  display failed ones!! is it possible!!